# harmonic extension on manifold

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Is the following claim true ?

> Given a smooth and bounded $u:M\to\mathbb{R}$ , where $(M,g)$ is a
> Riemannian manifold , then there exists a harmonic extension
> $\tilde{u}:M\times\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ as the unique bounded
> function satisfying $$\begin{cases}\Delta_{\bar{g}}\tilde{u}=0 \ \ \text{in} \ \ M\times\mathbb{R}^+\\ \tilde{u}=u \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{on} \ \ M\times\{0\}\end{cases}$$ where $\bar{g}=g+|dx|^2$ is
> the product metric on $M\times\mathbb{R}^+$ .

A hint was given to use the maximum principles . But I am not too familiar with that in manifold setting . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Do you know how to do it when $M = \mathbb R^n$ with the Euclidean metric?

Comment: I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259662/harmonic-extension) for $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

Comment: It's not very clear how that construction is related to what you want to construct here. They are dealing the unit disc, not a product.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  The text you quoted appears to be a *definition*, not a "claim".  Are you asking how to prove that such a harmonic extension really exists and is unique?

Comment: Yes , the latter . I edited the question accordingly .